# hide INFO window marker and show it dynamically

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I'm using this plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps
though the problem is not constrained 
I array of result which includes name, address and latlong.
I put the marker on map with for loop.
on click on marker the info window opens.

But what I want is to open particular marker info window from the click on the item of list view.

I'm posting some code to get subtle idea.

```
for (; i < noOfData; ++i) {
                (function(n) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var position = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(resultList[n].latitude, resultList[n].longitude);
                        markers.push(position);
                        $rootScope.map.addMarker({
                            'position': position,
                            'title': resultList[n].name,
                            'index': n,
                            'snippet': resultList[n].address,
                            "styles": {
                                'text-align': 'center',
                                'font-style': 'italic',
                                'color': 'red'
                            },
                            disableAutoPan: false
                        }, function(marker) {
                            $scope.listResults = resultList;
                            if ((+n + 1) == noOfData) {
                                var latLngBounds = new plugin.google.maps.LatLngBounds(markers);
                                console.log(hashCodeArrayOfMarkers.toString());
                                $rootScope.map.animateCamera({
                                    'target': latLngBounds,
                                    'zoom': 15,
                                    'duration': 1000 // 1 seconds
                                });
                            }
                            marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_CLICK, function() {
                                var indexOfMarkerClicked = marker.get("index");
                                marker.showInfoWindow();
                                $scope.clickList(indexOfMarkerClicked);
                                marker.showInfoWindow();
                                marker.getPosition(function(latLng) {
                                    $rootScope.map.animateCamera({
                                        'target': latLng,
                                        // 'zoom': 16,
                                        'duration': 400
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }, 0 + (0 * n));
                })(i);
            }
```

I want to get the same result from the item click on list.
I can move the camera to the marker as I have latLng but I want to open the info window of the same marker present on the lat lng.
Please help me.

Comment: you could simply trigger the click .tigger() http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ You have to Sync the list with the markers

Comment: Thank you. I hope you don't mind visiting https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Marker. They doesn't have trigger function for now. and also I've array of marker. I open the info_window of particular marker from addEventListener. Is there any way I can use key value or something like that. would be great if you help.

Comment: Are the list and markers generated from the same dataset?

Comment: yes, they are generated from same dataset. onMarkerClick I get the index value. with the index value I show the detailed information in popUp from the same dataset

Comment: if they are generated from the same dataset then the list index is equal to the marker. So simply get clicked List index .index() .eq() take this index trigger the onMarkerClick(indexFromList)

Comment: what this plugin is offering is, addEventListener returns you the marker 
then I can open the indo_window by
marker.showInfoWindow();

How can I will I get the listener event on the same marker which is selected from list. How to access that marker only. noob issues I get. please help

Comment: Hm, I don´t know the used plugin and don´t want to read it´s doc´s. But obviously you have an array "markers" where all markers are pushed in. So you have an defined index of each marker. Your list is generated from the same dataset, therefore you have the same order (index). Even if the plugin doesnt provide you a trigger functionality you can do it on your own (i guess) Sorry I can´t give you more informatione, If that doesn´t help you have to wait if someone knows this plugin.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the plugin offers no way to access or store reference to the markers, at least as far as I can tell. @AndroConsis did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dynamic Marker in Cordova    


    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;

             var data = [];

             var lat,long,snippet,title;

           document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

           var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                       console.log("this.responseText==="+this.responseText);
                       var parse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                       var invv = parse.info;

                        console.log("invv=="+invv);

                       var count = invv.length;

                       console.log("count=="+count);

                       var i;

                       for(i = 0 ;i < count ; i++){

                     lat = invv[i].lat;

                      long = invv[i].long;

                       snippet = invv[i].snippet;

                       title = invv[i].title;

                      console.log("title==="+title);

                        data.push({
                      "title" : title,
                      "position": new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),

                      });

                       }



                      console.log("data one==="+JSON.stringify(data));

                      sw(JSON.stringify(data));

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.100/tuts_rest/latlong.php", true);
                xmlhttp.send();



          console.log("data two==="+JSON.stringify(data));


          var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

          const GOOGLE = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
          var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv, {
            'camera': {
              'latLng': GOOGLE,
              'zoom': 17
            }
          });

        function sw(a){

        map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function() {


            console.log("data==="+a);

             var obj = JSON.parse(a);

             console.log("obj==="+obj);

             var nn = obj.length;

             console.log("nn==="+nn);



        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length;i++){

        addMarkers(obj, function(markers) {
        console.log("a==="+obj);
        console.log("hellooooo");
        console.log(markers[markers.length - 1]);
          markers[markers.length - 1].showInfoWindow();
        });

        }


        function addMarkers(data, callback) {
          var markers = [];
          function onMarkerAdded(marker) {

          console.log("marker==="+JSON.stringify(markers));

            markers.push(marker);
            if (markers.length === data.length) {
              callback(markers);
            }
          }
          data.forEach(function(markerOptions) {
            map.addMarker(markerOptions, onMarkerAdded);
          });

        }
           });



        }



        });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h3>PhoneGap-GoogleMaps-Plugin</h3>
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px" id="map_canvas"></div>
        <button id="button">Full Screen</button>
        </body>
        </html>


        JSON Response 

 {"status":1,"info":[{"lat":"-33.890542","long":"151.274856","snippet":"Hello"},{"lat":"-33.923036","long":" 151.259052","snippet":"Hello"}]}


    PHP Code

    <?php
        // Include confi.php
        include_once('config.php');



            $qur = mysql_query("select * from `latlong`");
            $result =array();
            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qur)){
                extract($r);
                $result[] = array("lat" => $lat, "long" => $long, 'snippet' => $snippet ,'title' => $title); 
            }
            $json = array("status" => 1, "info" => $result);

        @mysql_close($conn);

        /* Output header */
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($json);
        ?>

    Config.PHP

    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db('tuts_rest', $conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: You can *improve* the quality of your answer by explaining how or why it works. In this case, what have you done differently than the OP. It helps more to *explain* than just *show*.